# PHP7: how to use question marks(?? operator) for empty variable

Tags: php, php-7

Please Check this code:

```
$title1 = null; // maybe isset or not
$title2 = 'title2'; // maybe isset or not
$title3 = null; // maybe isset or not

$title = $title1 ?? $title2 ?? $title3;
```

I want print value of non-empty variable.

in this example, with

```
echo $title;
```

I want it print value  of `$title2` But it print `$title1` value.

I can do it with `switch` of `if`, But can I do it with `??` method?

```
if(isset($title1) && $title1)
  $title = $title1;
elseif(isset($title2) && $title2)
  $title = $title2;
elseif(isset($title3) && $title3)
  $title = $title3;
```

Comment: Your first example does print the value of $title2 for me on PHP 7.2. https://3v4l.org/bolKt

Comment: It works for me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5de84776cf52b78a979155337ee72fbcc79a5185

Comment: Are you sure `$title1` is `null` and not an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is definitely correct and should work as expected, outputting `'title2'`.

However, your condition `isset($title1) && $title1` is not the same. This is more like the 'Elvis' operarator `?:` checking for evaluation to boolean, except that the Elvis operator always returns a value (that might be null) and throws a notice on undefined operands. You would have to mute that by the `@` operator.

Your if-else-construct is almost equivalent to

```
$title = @$title1 ?: @$title2 ?: @$title3;
```

The only difference is that `$title` here is assigned anyway while in your if-else-construct `$title` is left untouched when all operands are evaluated to false.

Be aware that muting by the `@` operator also prevents critical errors to be shown, e.g. when using a function as operand.

An alternative is to define your own function. Arguments by value throw a notice on unset variables as well, however, arguments by reference do not. You can design a variadic function taking references:

```
function firstNonEmpty(&...$variableRefs)
{
  $v = null;         // ensure declaration since loop might not interate at all
  foreach ($variableRefs as $v)
    if($v) break;
  return $v ?: null; // we want null even if last value is like false
}

$c = 'value not considered to be empty';
$v = firstNonEmpty($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

Arguments by reference do not accept literals, thus appending some as default argument will not work. However, you can simply use the null-coalescing operator `??` in this case. There is fairly no use-case to add more than one default literal since you know at developtment time whether or not a literal evalualtes to false.

```
$v = firstNonEmpty($a, $b, $c, $d, 'default')  ; // does NOT work
$v = firstNonEmpty($a, $b, $c, $d) ?? 'default'; // DOES work

// One strange thing of PHP is that
$v = firstNonEmpty($a, ...[0, null, '', 'non-empty']); // DOES work as well
```

The latter literally creates an array of literals on the fly and references the destructed items. The only thinkable use-case having more than one literal would be generated code by `eval`.